# Xcode 7.1 update error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I tried updating to Xcode 7.1 from XCode 7.0.1. It is updated and now when I open the XCode it is still showing the previous one (7.0.1) and I didn't see any updates for XCode 7.1 in App Store. Then I searched for XCode in App Store, it is showing the XCode with 7.1 and Open button.Then when I open, its opening the old XCode(7.0.1).

I went through StackOverflow where people are suggesting to uninstall and install again. Is there any other way to get it resolved? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Close your Xcode and then reinstall it. Also check **Xcode -> About Xcode** and check the version

Answer (score 0):

Finally am answering my own question.

So to resolve this, the best way would be uninstalling all the version's of XCode  and then try installing XCode 7.1 from App store. This is not either stopping in the middle or breaking. Downloading and installing perfectly.

Note: If you are under development, all your work has to be stopped until installation.